# Keeping a layer synced across multiple files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

I am working on a web UI design and using adobe-photoshop. I have to make complete UI to show what exactly a screen would look after different interactions.

Say, the following is the basic layout of the design, with four sections A, B, C and D.
[image: Basic Layout for the design]

Now I have some 10 interactions and so 10 different files in which I'm showing that how section C varies on different interactions. So, I make the 10 designs and save them. Then later I realize that a change is required Section A. So I have to do the same change 10 times in all of those files.

**So, question is, is there a way, where I edit part(few layers) of a file once and it gets 'synced' across multiple PSD files?**

PS: I tried using Smart-Objects and saving sections as different PSDs and importing them, but nothing helped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add one smart object in multiple files in photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/how-to-add-one-smart-object-in-multiple-files-in-photoshop)

Comment: isn't it way easier to work with the layer comps palette in a single file instead of making different files?

Comment: I agree with bakabaka, create one PSD and export/toggle out each layergroup while keeping the common elements visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are external plugins that are able to do the thing, one such plugin is **[canlinkit](http://www.canlinkit.com/)**.

The other option that I found was using layer-comps. It can be referred [here](http://methodandcraft.com/videos/states-and-layer-comps).

Answer (score 0):

No. Photoshop does not contain any "publish <> subscribe" options, which is what you are describing is known as.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing inbuilt, but there is a plugin http://www.canlinkit.com

Comment: So this entire Q&A was nothing but spam then?

Comment: You feel so? After sharing this question on social networks, I got to know about the plugin. :)